# Kubernetes NFS mount permissions

Tags: linux, kubernetes, permissions, nfs

I have a problem with access permissions for group when mounting the NFS folder to the K8s POD.
When a file is created within the pod the permissions are read-only for the group on the NFS server.

(A) I have tried to set the security context on the pod:

`securityContext:`

`runAsUser: 1000`

`runAsGroup: 1000`

`fsGroup: 1000`

The id (1000) is the same as the group id on the NFS server.

(B) Also I tried with initContainer param:

`initContainers:`

`name: test`

`image: imagename`

`command: ["/bin/chmod","-R","660", "/data"]`

With this both case solutions the new created files have the following permissions which is not acceptable:

`-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 test.txt`

I have succeeded to create files within a pod with the needed permissions:

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 test.txt`

Only if I create a user on the running pod and switch to it with the same ID on the NFS server.

Comment: How are you creating the file within the pod?

Comment: @Dom normally there is an application that will create the files. For now either I am creating them manually or with the command parameter in the k8s deployment file.

Comment: Did solution of @Sunjay Jeffrish helped ?

Comment: @Malgorzata Nope.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use one of the two below
Method : Modify security context
securityContext:
runAsGroup: 65534
runAsUser: 65534
Method 2: Create an empty directory and mount it .
This should solve
- emptyDir: {}
name: data
mount it on to some volume /data

Comment: Could you explain the method 2 in details a bit. I tried both but unfortunately it did not help. How your second option would help? What would be the problem if it requires this workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Yes sure .

So what you are saying is the pod does not have permission to read or access the file . 
So what I would recommend you to do is 
Suppose say you want to mount a file in /etc/config . Then first create a empty dir and mount it to that /etc/config . Create an another volume mount(with the required data to be put in /etc/config) in to another directory say /config .

In the init container mv files from this config to the required emoty dir which was created already . This worked for me . Try it out and let me know.